# Change App language on first start with UITabBar

Tags: ios, localization, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a UITabBar. The first time the app runs the user needs to select a language in a modal view controller. I present the modalview in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` using:

```
 [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:languageVC animated:YES];
```

The problem is: the UITabbar is already loaded, so the language on the UITabbar won't be changed.

I can't do it in the main.m (like a lot of answers say) because the user needs to make a choice first.

So I tried waiting to load the TabBar until the user has chosen a language, but that doesnt work either.

I've seen another app do this (although this app hasn't got a UITabbar) and my client really needs it. But I have no clue how to fix this. Is it even possible with a UITabBar?

Comment: why do you ask the user to choose a language instead of using the system language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the language in AppDelegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as a global param.
Then you can set the tabbarItems title in each of the ViewControllers in the tabbar using

```
self.tabbarItem.title = @"abc123";
```

You could choose a text variable...

```
if ([language isEqualToString:@"german"]).....
else if ([language isEqualToString:@"english"]).....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and it worked, cheers! The only 'problem' is I have to use some if's in the ViewController's `init`. Not great code I guess, but it works so I'm not complaining.

Comment: But you should better use the systemLanguage and let the OS do the stuff using NSLocalizedString

Comment: Yeah I know, but my client wants it like this. We all know how annoying clients can be ;)

Comment: aah I see ;) This is true^^